# Drag&drop image in google sheets cell

Tags: image, google-sheets

Easy to drag-drop images from 'windows paint' to google sheet. But can't make it within the cell, so it can be resized with the cell accordingly.
The image is over the cell. I want that the image is instantly inside the cell and can be resized, deleted with the cell.
A sample file link can be shared.
Please help with this issue.

Comment: This is not at all a programming related question.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
Select the image, click 3 dots at the top right corner and click 'Put image in selected cell'.
That's it.